# php-ews -Occurrences of a meeting

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

have some trouble figure this out

Using php-ews: [jamesiarmes/php-ews](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews)

I am trying to book events with Recurrence and is working fine

After booking that meeting i want to fetch all occurrence of that meeting but can figuer it out! Can anyone help?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

So, you can't fetch all of the occurrences for that meeting. When the meeting is created, [it doesn't create an individual item for each occurrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/recurrence-patterns-and-ews). However, if you make a request to see calendar events within a timeframe, you can see individual occurrences in that time frame. If you want to get an individual occurrence, you can use the `GetItem` method and pass in an `OccurrenceItemId` [which is a combination of the Recurring Master Item Id and the Index of the occurance that you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-access-a-recurring-series-by-using-ews-in-exchange). What you do get, if you do a `GetItem` on the reccurance master that you create is information like ["How many occurances are there", "What's the first occurance" and "What's the last occurance"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-create-a-recurring-series-by-using-ews-in-exchange).

I hope this is helpful. I'm not able to show you exactly how to do it with `jamesiarmes/php-ews`, since I use and maintain a newer and easier to use version [`Garethp/php-ews`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews)

Comment: Thank for you answer!

If understand correctly i have 2 option right now:

1º I fetch all the meeting's in a time frame and filter what i need
2º I fetch each element using recurring master id and index and iterate each occurence

I am correct?

Comment: Correct. What's the use case that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to book meetings in my app and send it to external calendars like exchange!
In this moment i want to figure out how to i can update a single occurrence after create a reccurence meeting! But for that i need that particular occurrence id correct?